# IR setup for SQL Server on Azure VM

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have two SHIR (Scale-out mode) setup for extracting data from on-prem DB2 database systems.

Now target is SQL Server hosted in Azure VM. (As Azure SQL PaaS doesn't support XA distributed transactions)

My question do i need to setup two additional SHIR for target data load purpose. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need another IR or not depends. If you are exposing those databases to the internet (or your internal VPN), then just connect to them the same way you would connect to an Azure Sql Database. If you are not doing that, then yes, you need to install another IR inside those vms to extract data from them.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Worth to mention that azure integration runtime cannot use vnet/site-to-site vpn.